# How do I delete a specific folder from SharePoint using Power Shell script?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell-script

I have multiple main folders on SharePoint online each with their own sets of sub-folders and files. I need to delete a specific folder (and its full contents including any sub-folders and files) from each of those main folders. The folder has the same name across all main folders, but obviously it does not share the same filepath/url. This is what I have come up with so far from the research I have done. The code for deleting the folder is not even running as far as I can tell.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

```
$url_sharepoint = "https://company.sharepoint.com"
$library = "Sharepoint Library"
$deleteFolders = "Folder Name"
$source_folder = "Network Share:\filepath"

$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)
$cred = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $SecurePassword)
$clientContext.Credentials = $cred

$mylist = $clientContext.web.Lists.GetByTitle($library)
$clientContext.Load($mylist)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

#Get name of folder
$MainFolder = Split-Path $source_folder -Leaf

#upload folder to sharepoint
$UploadMainFolder = $mylist.RootFolder.Folders.Add($MainFolder)
$clientContext.Load($UploadMainFolder)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

$folders = $UploadMainFolder.Folders[$library].SubFolders

Foreach($folder in $folders)
{
    if ($folder.Name -match $deleteFolders)
    {
        $UploadMainFolder.Folders[$library].SubFolders.Delete($folder)
        Write-Host "Folder has been deleted!"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Folder has not been deleted!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tom, Have you tried the code snippet below ? Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSOM Method to delete the folder is DeleteObject(), for example:

`$targetFolder = $clientContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($folderRelativeUrl);
$targetFolder.DeleteObject();
$clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();`

I would also say overall your script is doing things the hard way.  You don't have to re-invent the PowerShell wheel.  You should install the Microsoft SharePoint Online PowerShell Module ([installation instructions here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online?view=sharepoint-ps) and [reference lookup here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/?view=sharepoint-ps)) and the Office PnP PowerShell Module ([installation instructions here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) and [reference lookup here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/?view=sharepoint-ps)) in your PowerShell window, where a lot of what you are trying to do has pre-built cmdlets to help.  These are essential for doing PowerShell against SharePoint Online.

Comment: Thanks, everyone.  Your suggestions pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the script as below:

```
$User = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"  
$Password = '*****'  
$url_sharepoint = "https://zheguo.sharepoint.com"
$library = "doc1"
$deleteFolders = "TestFolder"
$source_folder = "C:\TestFolder"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url_sharepoint)
$cred = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User, (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force)) 
$clientContext.Credentials = $cred

$mylist = $clientContext.web.Lists.GetByTitle($library)
$clientContext.Load($mylist)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

#Get name of folder
$MainFolder = Split-Path $source_folder -Leaf

#upload folder to sharepoint
$UploadMainFolder = $mylist.RootFolder.Folders.Add($MainFolder)
$clientContext.Load($UploadMainFolder)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

$folders = $mylist.RootFolder.Folders;
$clientContext.Load($folders);
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
Foreach($folder in $folders)
{
    if ($folder.Name -match $deleteFolders)
    {
        $Clientcontext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($folder.ServerRelativeUrl).DeleteObject();
        $ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        Write-Host "Folder has been deleted!"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Folder has not been deleted!"
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, everyone. Your suggestions pointed me in the right direction.